# Razor intellisense not working

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am using VS 2013 community with recent update. I just started to deploy new vb asp.net mvc 5 and tried to create my views, unfortunately when trying to put foreach with @ the intellisense seems to not work. I went over google and tried lot of fixs available but not one seems to be work for me. Do you know what could be the reason of that and how to enable it?

Comment: Try to update MVC packages using the nuget console to their latests versions and then rebuild the project. It always resolves this particular issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Update 4 installed?

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work? Maybe the problem lies on your code and not on VS2013.